# How can I open several web browser tabs using adb?

Tags: android, browser, adb

I've this answer about opening web browser using command line:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I want to know if is possible open more than one page in separate tabs at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Yes, actually, that's possible: use [`--ez create_new_tab true`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#EXTRA_CREATE_NEW_TAB) extra value. So, your command would look like:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com --ez create_new_tab true
```

You may create a shell script and put all the webpages you want to open there, and run.

<del>No, that's not possible.</del>

<del>The adb shell command you are using is same as [`Intent(String action, Uri uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri%29) constructor. The argument `uri` is a single variable, and is not an array. Hence, you can not feed more than one URI data.</del>